# Why can't I simulate focusin?

Tags: jquery, input, focus

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".boxForm .inputForm").focusin(function () {
        $(this).parent().addClass("focused");
    });
    $(".boxForm .inputForm").focusout(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            $(this).parent().removeClass("focused");
        }
    });

    $(".boxForm .inputForm").each(function () {
        var inputSel = $(this);
        inputSel.trigger("focusin");
        inputSel.trigger("focusout");
    });
});
```

and when I load the page, I want to simulate focusin/out (so I can keep the current state, even if the input val is autocompleted by browser itself).

It doesn't trigger those events (i.e. it doesn't add/remove that class `focused` if the input is blank or filled).

Comment: It does trigger all listeners http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/rLtussgz/3/ What debugging did you do to lead you to believe it's not being called?